# Dynamically return an AJAX action link from a controller action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to create a button on every row of a table of user names which toggles a lock/unlock function against each user. I want to use AJAX so I don't have to fetch all the users each time the page reloads. Its easy to have an AJAX action link in the table, but then I was stuck as to what to return from my controller after I have locked or unlocked the user. As a bit of a hack I return a string which is the html mark-up for a new AJAX action link. I theory I can click on the dynamically returned button, and continue to toggle the lock/unlock. To my amazement this actually worked, right up until I clicked on the button. The dynamic button does return the correct mark-up, but its on a blank page. To complicate matters further I'm using a custom helper to output my action link. I've detailed all the code below, if anyone can see what might be going wrong or a better way to handle this situation I'd be grateful.

HTML Helper:

```
 public static string ImageActionLink(this AjaxHelper helper, string imageUrl, string   altText, string actionName, object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
        builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
        var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName, routeValues, ajaxOptions);
        return link.ToHtmlString().Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
```

Controller:

```
public string Lock(Guid id)
    {
        IUserMethods userMethods = new UserMethods();

        ISMPUser user = userMethods.GetUser(id, CompanyId);
        string ajaxButtonHTML;

        //For some reason breaking the button HTML into substrings and appending them together for readability causes the anchor tag to render incorrectly.
        if (user.IsEnabled)
        {
            userMethods.AdministratorEnableAccount(CompanyId, CurrentUser.Id, user.Username, false);
            ajaxButtonHTML = "<a class=\"row_selected\" href=\"/MMWeb/Admin/Lock/" + id.ToString() + "\" onclick=\"Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, confirm: 'Lock User?', httpMethod: 'Post', updateTargetId: 'Enable-'" + user.Id + "' });\"><img src=\"/MMWeb/Content/Images/lock.png\" alt=\"Lock\"></a>";
        }
        else
        {
            userMethods.AdministratorEnableAccount(CompanyId, CurrentUser.Id, user.Username, true);
            ajaxButtonHTML = "<a class=\"row_selected\" href=\"/MMWeb/Admin/Lock/" + id.ToString() + "\" onclick=\"Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, confirm: 'Lock User?', httpMethod: 'Post', updateTargetId: 'Enable-'" + user.Id + "' });\"><img src=\"/MMWeb/Content/Images/unlock.png\" alt=\"Unlock\"></a>";
        }

        return ajaxButtonHTML;
    }
```

View:

```
<td id="<%= Html.Encode("Enable-" + user.Id) %>" class="icon-column">
                    <% if(user.IsEnabled)
                       { %>
                           <%--<img class="LockImg" alt="User Unlocked" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Images/unlock.png") %>" />--%>
                           <%= Ajax.ImageActionLink(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/unlock.png"), "Lock", "Lock", new { id = user.Id.ToString() }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Lock User?", HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "Enable-" + user.Id })%>
                    <% }
                       else
                       {%>
                           <%= Ajax.ImageActionLink(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/lock.png"), "Lock", "Lock", new { id = user.Id.ToString() }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Unlock User?", HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "Enable-" + user.Id })%>
                    <% }%>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might have several approaches, such as:

In the client end, when user click on a Lock/Unlock link, post an Ajax request to the server to change the locking status, send the user-Id with the Ajax call; Inside the 'Lock' action in server, the user locking status is updated and changed user status is returned as JSON data to the client. Based on the result, change the link's CSS to reflect the current locking status. Here is the sample code:

View:

```
<td>
 <a class='<%= (item.IsLocked ? "userLock" : "userUnlock") %>' 
    href='<%= Url.Action("ResetLock", new {id = item.Name, isLocked = item.IsLocked}) %>'>
 </a> 
</td>
```

Sample CSS:

```
.userLock,
.userUnlock
{
    background-image: url('/MMWeb/Content/Images/lock.png');
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;                        
}
.userUnlock
{
    background-image: url('/MMWeb/Content/Images/unlock.png');
}
```

javaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $('a.userLock, a.userUnlock').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault()
        var $this = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: $this.attr('href'),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (result.status == "Succeed") {
                    if (result.IsLocked == true) {                                
                        $this.removeClass('userUnlock').addClass('userLock');
                    }
                    else {                                
                        $this.removeClass('userLock').addClass('userUnlock');
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Failed to reset lock.');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ResetLock(Guid id)
    {
        //......
        //Update user locking status.
        //user.IsEnabled = !user.IsEnabled;
        //......

        var updatedModel = new { 
            status = "Succeed",
            IsLocked = user.IsEnabled
        };

        return Json(updatedModel);
    }
```

This approach keeps your controller action thin and DRY.
I think, generating the view as string inside the controller's action is not a good practice.

Another approach could be:

Wrap the locking view in a partial view(e.g. UserEnableView.ascx).
The 'Lock' action method should return the partial view, after updating the user's locking status. e.g.

```
public ActionResult Lock(Guid id)
{
    //......
    //Update user locking status.
    //....
   if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
      return PartialView( "UserLockView", updatedModel);
   }
   else{
      return View(updatedModel);
   }          
}
```